# How to install scanner brother dcp-7030 on ubuntu

Tags: drivers, scanner

When I try to follow the instructions here: [Scanner driver 64bit (deb package)](https://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadhowto.aspx?c=gb&lang=en&prod=dcp7030_all&os=128&dlid=dlf006642_000&flang=4&type3=566)

I get this error when I run this command in 3:

```
dpkg -i --force-all   brscan3-0.2.13-1.amd64.deb
```

Error:

> error: required read/write access to the dpkg database directory /var/lib/dpkg

How do I resolve this issue? This is fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04 I think. I have no idea what this means and I am a linux newbie. All I need is a button on desktop to scan a document from the scanner, which is Brother dcp-7030.

Comment: Try with: sudo dpkg -i --force-all brscan3-0.2.13-1.amd64.deb

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me on Ubuuntu 20.04 was:

download driver ("Scanner Setting file" not needed)
https://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadlist.aspx?c=de&lang=de&prod=dcp7030_all&os=128&flang=English

Install driver

```
sudo dpkg -i brscan3-0.2.13-1.amd64.deb
```

Put user in group scanner

```
sudo usermod -aG scanner $USER
```

setup sane

```
sudo /usr/local/Brother/sane/setupSaneScan3 -i
```

copy sane-files

```
sudo ln -sf /usr/lib64/sane/libsane-brother* /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane
```

and

```
sudo nano /lib/udev/rules.d/60-libsane.rules
```

there add

```
# Brother scanners
ATTRS{idVendor}=="04f9", MODE="0660", GROUP="scanner", ENV{libsane_matched}="yes"
```

and in

```
sudo nano /etc/sane.d/brother.conf
```

add

```
# Brother USB
# For libusb support for unknown scanners use the following command
# usb <vendor ID> <product ID>
usb 04f9 01eb
```